# No syntax for Nonclustered index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, index

So, I have seen people discussing about differences between clustered V Non Clustered index, however, I didn't see any syntax for Non Clustered Index in MysQL. How does MySQL creates Nonclustered Index?

The only thing I saw is Secondary Index in the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)

Comment: What is there on that [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html) that you're having problems with?

Comment: I want to find out syntax for Non Clustered Index in MySQL. Can you help me with that?

Comment: My take on the docco is that your PRIMARY KEY is clustered, the others not (they can't be). As far as I can see, all you have to do to declare a non-clustered index is CREATE TABLE Blah(fields.... KEY/INDEX field_name...). Those KEY or INDEXs will be indexed, but non clustered. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777975/when-to-use-sql-no-cache) post. You might also want to look at [this](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html).

Answer (score 2):

InnoDB:  The PRIMARY KEY is UNIQUE and clustered -- always.
Secondary keys are non-clustered.  They have the PRIMARY KEY (not a rownum or rowid) in the leaf node of the secondary key index.

MyISAM:  Keys are non-clustered -- always.  The leaf nodes of indexes have a pointer (think: byte offset) into the data file to get from the index to the data.  `ALTER TABLE tbl ORDER BY ...;` will reorder the "data", thereby temporarily give you clustering on whatever you ORDERed BY.

MySQL decided those were "good enough".  I have only very rarely found a need for something else.

Comment: Not "always". (exception: if an InnoDB table has not a Primary key, then the first (whatever that means) Unique not null Key is the clustered index.)

Comment: (exception 2: if an InnoDB table has no Primary and no Unique index, then a secret 6-byte column is used as the clustered index.)

Comment: @ypercube is correct.  However, it is "bad form" to not explicitly spell out a PRIMARY KEY on InnoDB tables.